# Create CSV file using javascript or any other native script?

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I am new to nativescript, I need a simple application to be created for iOS, using a form (some text fields) I need to create a csv file and send it to some email address as an attachment. Can someone please share some code snippet or documentation to do that?

Comment: What is your data held in? An array? JSON?

Comment: The data will be in json format!

Comment: Is this a help request, or a 'write my program/homework' request? What have you tried? What have you researched? You can use the `file-system` module to write a file, then use the `util` module to open the email application with intents to send the file.